# Xamarin.Forms - SkiaSharp drawing in backgroud thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms application. I want use a SkiaSharp library to draw an series of line and points. It's possible draw on background thread?

From [Microsft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.views.forms.skcanvasview.invalidatesurface?view=skiasharp-views-forms-1.68.0), the `SKCanvasView.InvalidateSurface()` method must be called from UI thread.

Comment: My understanding tells me the code that makes changes on the UI will always be on the `MainThread`, the rest can always be on a background thread and it should not cause any issues

Comment: I'm "translating" the old Android App. I need to obtain some data from a USB device from a background thread and in parallel I need to draw.
So all my code must be on background thread otherwise the UI will block. It's a real time drawing

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but anyway.

What you can do from the backgroundthread is invalidating the canvas.

```
XAML:
<skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="canvas" PaintSurface="OnCanvasViewPaintSurfaceAsync" />

CODE:
SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args;

// Update canvas through background task    
async void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Invalidating surface due to data change
    canvas?.InvalidateSurface();
}

async void OnCanvasViewPaintSurfaceAsync(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs args1)
{
    args = args1;
    await drawAsync();
}

public async Task drawAsync()
{

     SKImageInfo info = args.Info;
     SKSurface surface = args.Surface;
     SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add your code in a parallel task like this

Public Task MyBeautifulPicture(){

Task.run((n)=>{

SKCanvas.DrawRect(etc,etc);
}).ConfigureAwait(true);

}

Comment: Did you try this code? I have tried to put my code for draw some lines `SKCanvas.DrawLine()` and an exception was thrown.